# wxpython: How to create wxChoice contents from a list?

Tags: list, wxpython

I have a choice box

```
self.chHead = wx.Choice(self.nbItemPane, -1, choices=[])
```

And I have a list

```
items=[equipment('Head','BIG HELMET',555,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0),
       equipment('Head','MED HELMET',555,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0),
       equipment('Head','SMA HELMET',555,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0),
       equipment('Shoulders','BIG SHOULDERS',555,5,5,5,5,5,0,0,0,0,0)
      ]
```

What I want to have happen is that the choice values of my choicebox will be drawn from the list of items.  So in this case when you selected the dropdown of self.chHead you would only see 'BIG HELMET', 'MED HELMET', and 'SMA HELMET' as options

Equipment is defined as

```
class equipment(object):
    def __init__(self, slot, name, armor, str, int, wis, dex, end, val, tough, power, crit, hit):
        """
        Model of the Equipment Object
        Contains the followign attributes:
        """

        self.slot = slot
        self.name = name
        self.armor = armor
        self.str = str
        self.int = int
        self.wis = wis
        self.dex = dex
        self.end = end
        self.val = val
        self.tough = tough
        self.power = power
        self.crit = crit
        self.hit = hit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your definition of `equipment`.  I'll pretend it's a class with functions `GetSlot()` and `GetName()` for retrieving the first two fields.  You could create your `choices` list from the list of items like this:

```
choices = [item.GetName() for item in items if item.GetSlot() == 'Head']
self.chHead = wx.Choice(self.nbItemPane, -1, choices=choices)
```

The only problem with that is that you don't have an easy way to know which item from the `items` list your selection refers to, especially if two or more items can have the same name.  You can solve that by setting the `clientData` for each list item to the corresponding index of the `items` list.  Do this instead:

```
self.chHead = wx.Choice(self.nbItemPane, -1)
for i in range(len(items)):
    if items[i].GetSlot() == 'Head':
        self.chHead.Append(item=item[i].GetName(), clientData=i)
```

Comment: I have added the class info I have for equipment.

Comment: The .append was what I needed.  Tks mucho